# How to use the have_rows() within a php function using variables and parameters

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to create a php function which access information from a **AdvanceCustomFields** plugin on my **Wordpress** site. In my function i use the **have_rows()**, **get_row_layout()**, **the_sub_field()** functions. These functions are used like this:

```
 <?php 

function accessingMainLayoutField()
{
    if( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ):
        while (have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ) : the_row();
            if(get_row_layout() == 'layout_name'):

                the_sub_field('sub_field_name');

            elseif(get_row_layout() == ''):

                echo "Error2";

            endif;
        endwhile;                               
    else:
        echo "Error1";
    endif;
}
?>
```

The code above is a example of how the working code looks like, but i would much rather use the function's parameters.

This would be an example of this:

```
<?php 

    function accessingMainLayoutField($mainfield, $layout, $valuefield)
    {
        if( have_rows($mainfield) ):
            while (have_rows($mainfield) ) : the_row();
                if(get_row_layout() == $layout):

                    the_sub_field($valuefield);

                elseif(get_row_layout() == ''):

                    echo "Error2";

                endif;
            endwhile;                               
        else:
            echo "Error1";
        endif;
    }
    ?>
```

And then to call this function I'd write:

```
<?php
function accessingMainLayoutField("'flexible_content_field_name'", "'layout_name'", "'sub_field_name'");
?>
```

But for some reason, this code does not work. The function "echoes" "Error1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function, and only use one set of quotation marks:

```
accessingMainLayoutField('flexible_content_field_name', 'layout_name', 'sub_field_name');
```